# How do I delete a mongodb collection from a restapi

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

I'm trying to delete a user from my mongo collection but unable to figure out how sharing my register request and a bed attempt on my part.

```
api.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  Account.register(new Account({ username: req.body.email,
    phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber, nyuId: req.body.nyuId}), req.body.password, function(err, account) {
    if (err) {
      return res.json({
                        "status": false,
                        "code" : 500,
                        "message": 'An error occurred: ' + err
                      });
    }
    passport.authenticate(
      'local', {
        session: false
    })(req, res, () => {

      });
      res.status(200).send('Welcome to nyu created new account');+      });
    });
  });
```

need help here.

```
api.delete(':id', (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
    Account.findByIdAndRemove({_id: req.body.id }, (err) => {
      if (!err) {
             res.sendStatus(404);
      }
      else {
            res.sendStatus(200);
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Account.findByIdAndRemove(id, function(err){

    if(err) {
        // handle the error
    } else {
        // your logic
    }

})
```

Comment: I have updated my request can you correct my delete request.